# Parsing RAW HTTP headers and converting it to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash, http-headers

I have an endpoint which receives a parameter called `headers` which contains RAW string of HTTP headers. I need this string to be converted to JSON/Hash object.

**Example values of `headers`:**

```
"Received: by mx0047p1mdw1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id 6WCVv7KAWn Wed, 27 Jul 2016 20:53:06 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from mail-io0-f169.google.com (mail-io0-f169.google.com [209.85.223.169]) by mx0047p1mdw1.sendgrid.net (Postfix) with ESMTPS id AA9FFA817F2 for <example@example.comom>; Wed, 27 Jul 2016 20:53:06 +0000 (UTC)
Received: by mail-io0-f169.google.com with SMTP id b62so81593819iod.3 for <example@example.comom>; Wed, 27 Jul 2016 13:53:06 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=sendgrid.com; s=ga1; h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to; bh=DpB1CYYeumytcPF3q0Upvx3Sq/oF4ZblEwnuVzFwqGI=; b=GH5YTxjt6r4HoTa+94w6ZGQszFQSgegF+Jlv69YV76OLycJI4Gxdwfh6Wlqfez5yID 5dsWuqaVJZQyMq/Dy/c2gHSqVo60BKG56YrynYeSrMPy8abE/6/muPilYxDoPoEyIr/c UXH5rhOKjmJ7nICKu1o99Tfl0cXyCskE7ERW0=
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=1e100.net; s=20130820; h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to; bh=DpB1CYYeumytcPF3q0Upvx3Sq/oF4ZblEwnuVzFwqGI=; b=Sq6LVHbmywBdt3sTBn19U8VOmelfoJltz8IcnvcETZsYwk96RBxN+RKMN5fOZSKw4j 15HrgdIFfyDmp67YK0ygvOITlTvZ6XY5I0PtnvDtAQt79kS3tKjI3QKJoEp/ZjIjSzlL KG7agl6cxFgBbIN0yHWBOvy3O+ZXY8tZdom1yOvULjmjW1U9JkdOs+aJ6zq4qhZX/RM/ tIgLB461eJ5V95iQDDc5Ibj9Cvy4vJfXLQRO0nLVQAT2Yz58tkEO1bDZpWOPAyUNneIL yhIWp+SpbuqhMA68mq0krG1PjmWalUbpVcGJIGuOKB9mQFFo/MqdrUCjvYnyo1jPLPeX psdQ==
X-Gm-Message-State: AEkoousvdxmDoxLlTUYJ1AOmCGJv77xRBBlfKv6YrthH0M2NueMwlOxUD6t8nidE9uonXbdJ/DQy/chmHUnN//a4
X-Received: by 10.107.6.101 with SMTP id 98mr38024553iog.41.1469652785829; Wed, 27 Jul 2016 13:53:05 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.107.48.17 with HTTP; Wed, 27 Jul 2016 13:53:05 -0700 (PDT)
From: Sender Name <example@example.com>
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2016 14:53:05 -0600
Message-ID: <CAN_P_JMvV7ZpAQhOnDienypLrJmuhN=LQWweu4yScw4jQyXY2w@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Different File Types
To: example@example.comom
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=001a113f8ad03e85160538a4343c
"
```

Please help me to convert the above HTTP header string to JSON.

Thanks..

Comment: How do you expect the output to look like? Plain? Nested? Key format?

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for asking. It needs to be a normal key, value pair of hash/JSON. I think the string I have provided doesn't have any nested keys and I don't know what do you mean by Plain format?

Comment: I would expect the 4th for example line to be parsed into a nested structure like this: `dkim_signature: { v: 1, a: 'rsa-sha256' ... }`

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice that. Just a key value pair is enough. No need to be nested.

Comment: I need the same in C# code. Any  sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by carriage returns <kbd>⏎</kbd>, then split each line by colon, two parts at most, then convert the result to the hash:

```
input.split($/).map { |line| line.split(':', 2).map(&:strip) }.to_h
```

The `strip` operation in between is optional.